# How to edit normal direction

Tags: cycles-render-engine, faces, edges, normals, normal-map

I am trying to point the face normals to another direction than the face is facing. I want the face to be about 45 degrees and the normal pointing straight up. But no matter what I use, normal edit, as seen in this screenshot

[image]
http://prntscr.com/md9u8w

I am trying to get the normals to point straight up. I had luck making trees on a similar kind of geometry (where it's only planes with normals pointing straight out, torwards a sphere instead of the direction of the face). But for some reason, now the same thing, done the exact same way, in the exact same scene, with exact same objects used to data transfer or normal edit modifiers, it just won't work, no matter what setting I change or object I use.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something comparable to Custom Vertex Normals, like this guy demonstrates here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAGEGBulzSU

Answer (score 3):

**If you need all the normals to point upwards it's quite simple.**

- Create a new plane.
- Enable Auto-Smooth on your main object.

[image]

- Add a Data Transfer Modifier to your main object.
- Set the Plane as source Object and check Face Corner Data and enable
  Custom Normals. Your object will now copy the normals from the Plane.

[image]

---

**If you want different normals to point in different directions you can do the same using Vertex Groups.**

- Create a new plane and angle it to the direction you want your normals to point. Create a new plane for every direction you need. Name them accordingly.

[image]

- Create a Vertex group for each direction. Name them accordingly. Assign the vertices  you need to their desired vertex group.

[image]

- Enable Auto-Smooth
- Add a Data Transfer Modifier for each Vertex group. Set the desired Plane as source Object along with its Vertex group. Check Face Corner Data and enable Custom Normals.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To point normals in a specific direction there is the [Normal Edit Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/normal_edit.html).
Also works with vertex groups for multiple directions.

1. Place Object in direction Normals shoud face
2. Add Normal Edit Modifier
3. Enable Autosmooth in Object settings if nessesary **(step missing in GIF)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the normal direction with the **Blend4Web** Add-on.

Download it here: https://www.blend4web.com/en/downloads/